# Using if_else for string search

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to replace the name of the US states with the string " United States".

```
Country<-data.frame(Name=c(" China"," Japan"," Florida"," Canada"," Texas"))
Country$Name<-as.character(Country$Name)
Country
      Name
1    China
2    Japan
3  Florida
4   Canada
5    Texas

str(Country)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Name: chr  " China" " Japan" " Florida" " Canada" ...
```

Below is the DPLYR command I used. It doesn't work.  I use state.name for this purpose.

```
Country%>%mutate(Name=if_else(Name %in% state.name, " United States",Name))
      Name
1    China
2    Japan
3  Florida
4   Canada
5    Texas
```

I tried to use str_detect, but it gives multiple output for the search on state.name. ( FALSE FALSE TRUE...… ). Hence unable to succeed with the condition check.

Comment: Your attempt works but you have whitespace around the `Name`. Try `Country%>%mutate(Name=if_else(trimws(Name) %in% state.name, " United States",Name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` from base R to do it

```
Country <- within(Country, Name <- ifelse(trimws(Name) %in% state.name, "United States",trimws(Name)))
```

Comment: The problem is NOT `ifelse`. It is because there is a leading space and thus cannot match with `state.name` (as mentioned in comments)

Comment: @Sotos thanks, now the answer is updated

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The answer works as intended (as far as I understand the question).

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that `%in%` only checks for exact matches. The names in your `data.frame` have whitespace at the beginning while `state.name` hasn't. So you need to remove this whitespace before comparing the two.

You can either remove the whitespace (with `trimws`) from the `Name` column before comparison:

```
library(dplyr)

Country %>%
  mutate(Name = trimws(Name)) %>% 
  mutate(Name = if_else(Name %in% state.name, "United States", Name))
#>            Name
#> 1         China
#> 2         Japan
#> 3 United States
#> 4        Canada
#> 5 United States
```

Or just within the comparison, which will preserve the whitespace (I don't see a reason why you would want that but just in case):

```
Country %>%
  mutate(Name = if_else(trimws(Name) %in% state.name, "United States", Name))
#>            Name
#> 1         China
#> 2         Japan
#> 3 United States
#> 4        Canada
#> 5 United States
```

A third possibility would be to use string replacement, for example, with the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
Country %>% 
  mutate(Name = stri_replace_all_fixed(Country$Name, state.name, "United States", 
                                       vectorize_all = FALSE, stri_opts_regex(case_insensitive = TRUE)))
#>             Name
#> 1          China
#> 2          Japan
#> 3  United States
#> 4         Canada
#> 5  United States
```

I wouldn't recommend this either but included it since you have a few more options (e.g., `case_insensitive`) if your strings are more complicated than what's in your sample data.